# Simple VBA Code: Filling Cell with text is empty

Tags: vba, excel

this is for learning purpose only. I have this code below. I want that program will go and check every cell from 1 to 999. If the cell is empty it will fill it up with text. Nothing happening with this code:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iRowEmpty

On Error Resume Next
'//Your Line here which causes 1004 error
If Err.Number > 0 Then
  Debug.Print Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
End If

i = 0
iRowEmpty = Rows(i, 1)

Do Until i = 999
    i = i + 1
    iRowEmpty = Rows(i, 1)
        If IsEmpty(iRowEmpty) = True Then
           iRowEmpty.Value = "Text..."

        End If
Loop
MsgBox ("The End")
'Note: Debug shortcut keys i use in PC: Step Into (F8), Step Over (Shift + F8), Step Out (Ctrl + Shift + F8)

End Sub
```

The spreadsheet has 1 column of data, in most cases every second cell is empty.

Comment: you have `On Error Resume Next` so the error **Application-defined or object-defined error** when trying to evaluate `Rows(i, 1)`  is ignored... you should use `Cells(i,1)` - and you should **not use On error resume next...**

Comment: also, `IsEmpty` is for variables in VBA, not cells

Comment: you sould also use `Cells(i, 1).Value = "Text..."` to set or check a value

Comment: Yeah thanks for feedback. I was recording the macro, and it showed me Rows. Could you explain why Rows has error 1004, and Cells not? You said also that isEmpty is for variables not cells. What do you mean, and if it so, why is it working then? And the last question: how to make in comment isEmpty in blockquote? :)

Comment: @BartBart This is better asked in a separate question *(try to incorporate this question into the new one)*

Comment: @Bart-Bart: have a look at [MSDN: Range.Rows Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-rows-property-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Our-Man-in-Bananas: Ok I get it, so Rows should have a form Rows(i), and I used form Rows(i,j) and the 1004 error occurs. Still would like to know what you have meant about IsEmpty (that is for variables in VBA, not cells) <- I mean what is alternative then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: If you want to check the Cells then you should use

```
Cells(i,1)
```

Second: iRowEmpty is just a copy of the Cell and not a direct reference so you should use

```
Cells(i,1).Value = "Text..."
```

To assign the value to the cell.

So in the end you have something like this

```
i = 0
Do Until i = 999
    i = i + 1
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) = True Then
           Cells(i, 1).Value = "Text..."
        End If
Loop
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

To clarify:

> **Syntax**
>
> The syntax for the ISEMPTY function in Microsoft Excel is:
>
> IsEmpty( value )
>
> **value**
>
> The value that you want to test. **If value is a blank cell or
>   uninitialized variable, this function will return TRUE**. Otherwise,
>   the function will return FALSE.
>
> **Applies To**:
>
> Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2011 for Mac, Excel 2010, Excel 2007,
>   Excel 2003, Excel XP, Excel 2000

Taken from: [TechOnTheNet](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isempty.php)

Comment: You should try it yourself or search more specifically for IsEmpty function in excel. [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isempty.php)

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. I didn't edit my initially posted code.